# Comparing with three values without repeating it three times

Tags: coldfusion

Is this correct on ColdFusion (do not have a running environment until next week)?

```
<cfif variableName IN (11,12,13,14,15,16) >
.................
................
</cfif>
```

or do I have to repeat it 6 times?

```
<cfif variableName EQ 11 OR variableName EQ 12 OR variableName EQ 13 OR  
variableName EQ 14 OR variableName EQ 15 OR variableName EQ 16>
..........................
..........................
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why not use GT and LT?

Comment: @TonyDong That was en example or ordered numbers. The real values are   6 digits numbers not in any order, so I have to check for those numbers and can't check for a range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. However, you can enclose the list of values in quotes and use list functions like [ListFind](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfind.html) or [ListFindNoCase](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfindnocase.html):

```
<cfif listFind("11,12,13,14,15,16", variableName)>
    variableName was found. do something.
</cfif>
```

> do not have a running environment until next week

You can always download [CF Express](https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html) in the interim. Just download the .zip, extract and double click the `{cf_root}\bin\cfstart.bat` file to start CF using the built in web server (note - runs on port 8500 by default).

For quick tests, another option is online sites like http://trycf.com or http://cflive.net/.